# Saving raw data into local storage in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get raw data from a URL and save it into a local storage folder in `Laravel 5.1`. A challenge that I am having is that it's only saving one file in the storage folder which just replaces the existing file, with a file name **Resource id #11**, but it's supposed to add multiple files according to time stamp.

Below is my code I am using in my controller:

```
public function add(Request $request) {
    $postdata = $request->getContent();
    $myfile = fopen(time().str_random(), "w");

    Storage::disk('local')->put($myfile, $postdata);

    fclose($myfile);
}
```

Anyone with an idea of how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `fopen` and `fclose` when using the laravel `Storage` facade. Right now you are opening a stream and using that stream as the file name.

You can just do something like this:

```
public function add(Request $request) {
  $postdata = $request->getContent();
  $myfile = time().str_random();
  Storage::disk('local')->put($myfile, $postdata);
}
```

Comment: This exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.